# How to add foreign key for schema table when class is not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Just trying to add a new table into existing database using a [code-first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database) approach but here is a little issue, see this

Initial migrations:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),

            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
            });

 }
```

Now I have created a table inside `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Order model class:

```
public class Orders
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers.Id")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but this attribute is not creating a foreign key

```
[ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers.Id")]
```

Please help me solve this ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the ForeignKey like below:

```
public class Orders
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AspNetUsers")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }                              
    public AspNetUsers AspNetUsers{get;set;}
}
```

You can refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).